# Multivariate Multiple Regressions

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-regression, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I have 24 multiple regression equations (24 dependent series and 24 independent series) and want the coefficients to be equal.

How do I combine them?

I allow for correlation of errors and tried SUR, but that required me to write separate restrictions for each **pair** of coefficients to be equal.  This means that for each parameter I need to write 12x13 restrictions.

So I decided to go with separate multivariate regressions, is there a way to solve them simultaneously?

I cannot solve them separately neither because 6 of my parameters are constants, STATA omits them before even going into SUR.

I combined indep series like these:

```
x1 <- cbind(v1,a1,d1,e1lag,v1_e1lag,a1_e1lag,d1_e1lag,j1,k1,r1,m1,dum1,dum2)
x2 <- cbind(v2,a2,d2,e2lag,v2_e2lag,a2_e2lag,d2_e2lag,j2,k2,r2,m2,dum1,dum2)
x3 <- cbind(v3,a3,d3,e3lag,v3_e3lag,a3_e3lag,d3_e3lag,j3,k3,r3,m3,dum1,dum2)
x4 <- cbind(v4,a4,d4,e4lag,v4_e4lag,a4_e4lag,d4_e4lag,j4,k4,r4,m4,dum1,dum2)
x5 <- cbind(v5,a5,d5,e5lag,v5_e5lag,a5_e5lag,d5_e5lag,j5,k5,r5,m5,dum1,dum2)
```

For 5 series, do I write it as below?

```
mrmodel <- lm(cbind(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5) ~ cbind(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5))
```

This one did not work, **I want to regress y1~x1 , y2~x2 ... simultanously using the same coefficients ..**

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi Begum, welcome! Could you maybe write down the formula of the multivariate regression you want to estimate?

Comment: Just stack your vectors: you get a single model $y \sim x.$  The `R` function to do that is `rbind`.  This is a *multiple* regression, not a multivariate regression.

Comment: @whuber Multiple vs multivariate - of which one SUR is a special case?